# Change top panel font in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell

Using default Yaru theme, I want to change the font of top panel to match modified fonts in [Gnome Tweaks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks).
Since Yaru theme has no shell theme as noticed:

[image: Gnome Tweaks appearance settings]

I can't find the required CSS file in Yaru directory that include shell variables to modify.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Default Ubuntu 19.04

the User Shell Theme is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

If you want to use your own shell theme, you need to install user-shell theme. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

If you are using the default one,

open the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` and edit the content like below. Please note that I have already added the line `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` in below content.

```
/* TOP BAR */
    #panel {
      background-color: #1d1d1d;
      font-weight: 450;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      height: 1.86em;
      font-feature-settings: "tnum"; }
```

[image]

for Example: In the belwo .gif I have changed the top bar font from "Keraleeyam" to "Dyuthi"

[image]