# Change Ubuntu top bar font

Tags: themes, fonts, gnome-shell

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I installed a Mac OS theme, and I'm using the "Garuda" font, is it possible to apply it in the top bar? 
I also want to change the font in the login and lockscreen, is it possible?

Comment: hi.. please try to ask one question at a time..

Comment: also have a look on this https://askubuntu.com/a/1138059/739431

Comment: @PRATAP i tried but it only changes the font size, not the actual font, or maybe i didnt follow the instructions well (im new)

Comment: from the possible duplicate link.. add font-family line `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` Change the font with your font.. make sure you have the font in your system.. read both the links..